# Fancybox v1.3 height

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

Why height of fancybox isn't equal the height of content?

```
fancybox-inner height: 210px
partdialog height: 273px!
```

Fancybox

```js
$(".fancy_my").fancybox({
   autoScale: false,
   margin: 20,
   width: 500,
   top: 0,
   left: 0,
   autoSize: false,
   showCloseButton: true,
   hideOnContentClick: false,
   hideOnOverlayClick: false,
   scrolling: 'no'
});
```

```html
<div id='partDialog' style='margin-left:0px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:28px;margin-right:30px;width:250px;'>
   <input type='hidden' id='partDialogID' />
   <div id='chooseTypeHeader'>Выберите удобный для вас формат участия в мероприятии</div>
   <div id='chooseTypeList' style='margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px'>
      <input type='radio' name='partFormat' id='fullTime' value='false' checked='checked' onclick="$('[name=cityChoose]').removeAttr('disabled')" />
      <label for='fullTime'>Личное присутствие</label>
      <br />
      <input type='radio' name='partFormat' id='absentia' value='true' onclick="$('[name=cityChoose]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')" />
      <label for='absentia'>Дистанционное участие</label>
   </div>
   <div id='cityListHeader'>Укажите город вашего присутствия в случае очного участия в мероприятии:</div>
   <div id='cityList' style='margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px'></div>
   <div style="overflow:hidden;">
      <a onclick="$.fancybox.close();$('#fancybox-outer').attr('style','');" class='goSearch'>Отмена<span></span></a>
      <a onclick="SendApply($('#partDialogID').val(), $('[name=partFormat]:checked').val(), $('[name=cityChoose]:checked').val());$.fancybox.close();$('#fancybox-outer').attr('style','');" class='goSearch' style="color:#c70000">Принять участие<span></span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your HTML content doesn't have a `height` style and it's set to `auto`. If you want exact size of fancybox according to your content, set dimensions to it and set fancybox's `autoDimensions` to `false`